# Deprecated display width for integer data types

Tags: mysql, sql

I read

> As of MySQL 8.0.17, the display width attribute is deprecated for
> integer data types; you should expect support for it to be removed in
> a future version of MySQL.

in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html

What are the problems with the display width attribute? Is it a general SQL problem, so other dbms also remove this attribute in the future/ have removed it in the past?

Comment: @basha04 There is no real case error. This question is about the reasoning to make the attribute deprecated.

Comment: *What are the problems with the display width attribute?* DBMS stores and processes data. Displaying is not DBMS task.

Comment: This attribute deprecating instructs you: 1) If your software tries to use this attribute for possible values range restriction then use CHECK constraint instead. 2) If you use column with specified width length and zerofill then use explicit zerofill performed by according expression (LPAD function) instead.